# Dynamic styles for GWT cellTable cells

Tags: css, gwt, celltable

I'm having an issue using GWT. I'm building the columns of a cellTable and I want the style of a cell to depends of the value of that cell:

```
Column<MyProxy, MyProxy> editButtonColumn = new Column<MyProxy, MyProxy>(new ActionCell<MyProxy>("", new ActionCell.Delegate<MyProxy>() {
        @Override
        public void execute(MyProxy record) {
            if (object.isEditable()) {
                doSomething(record);
            }
        }
    })) {
        @Override
        public MyProxy getValue(MyProxy object) {
            if (object.isEditable()) {
                this.setCellStyleNames("editButtonCell");
            }
            return object;
        }
    };
```

I've checked in debug mode the style "editButtonCell" is applied correctly. But in the HTML generated, the style is missing everytime for the FIRST ROW... It looks like a GWT bug, but maybe you folks have a better explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't checked but most probably the opening of the cell has already been generated by the time `getValue` is called, so `setCellStyleNames` will only apply to the remaining cells in the column.

The right way to do it is to *override* [`getCellStyleNames`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Column.html#getCellStyleNames%28com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context,%20T%29) of the column to return the CSS class name or not depending on the cell value.

---

BTW, you can then extend `IdentityColumn` as the `getValue` then becomes trivial.

Comment: Great ! The 'getCellStyleNames' solution worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.