# GWT TextColumn in CellTable -> Horizontal alignment

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

I am trying to align a column in my cell table to the right. Therefore I use the "setHorizontalAlignment" of my column object. The resulting cell is actually rendered with the "align=right", but it is not aligned to the right because the cell contains another div that fills the complete cell.

Is this a bug in GWT or am I doing it wrong?

```
TextColumn<String> myColumn = new TextColumn<String>() {
    @Override
    public String getValue(String myObj) {
        return myObj;
    }
};
myColumn.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
myCellTable.addColumn(myColumn, "anyColumnName");
```

[image]

I know I can also align it right via CSS, but I hope, I can get this approach working because it seems to be the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using css and [Column#setCellStyleNames()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Column.html#setCellStyleNames%28java.lang.String%29).

Sample code:

```
myColumn.setCellStyleNames("rightAlign");
```

css:

```
.rightAlign{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Note: change css as per your requirement

Comment: For another sample code have a look at [Dynamic styles for GWT cellTable cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361648/dynamic-styles-for-gwt-celltable-cells)

Comment: There is no need to do that if the alignment is set on the column.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin yes you are right but if OP want to change it just for one column and a global css for all others columns to be left.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same code, and it renders the same way - with a `div` element that takes 100% of the width. And the text inside this cell is displayed aligned to the right - as it should. So this is not a GWT bug.

There is another style in your CSS that interferes here. Most likely, you have something like this in your CSS:

```
td {
    text-align: left;
}
```