# CellTable Column Alignment to Right/Center

Tags: css, gwt

I need the Cell Table Column Alignment to be on Right/Center.Is it Possible to do using any `GWT CellTable` API Method? How to Achieve this?Any suggestion [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good answer how to add a style name to a cell.

[Dynamic styles for GWT cellTable cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361648/dynamic-styles-for-gwt-celltable-cells)

A solution can look like this:

```
t.addColumn(new TextColumn<String>()
        {

            @Override
            public String getValue(String object)
            {
                return object;
            }

            @Override
            public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, String object)
            {

                return super.getCellStyleNames(context, object) + " right";
            }
        });
```

in your css class add:

```
.right{
    text-align: right;
}
```